# app_1 | standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, docker-multi-stage-build

I have a golang application and I created dockerfile, which make multi-stake build.
But I catch this error `app_1  | standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"`  every time when try to do `docker-compose up`.
Dockerfile:

```
# Start from the latest golang base image
FROM golang:1.13 as builder

# Set the Current Working Directory inside the container
WORKDIR /memesbot

# Copy go mod and sum files
COPY go.mod go.sum ./

# Download all dependencies. Dependencies will be cached if the go.mod and go.sum files are not changed
RUN go mod download

# Copy the source from the current directory to the Working Directory inside the container
COPY . .

# Build the Go app
RUN go build -o /memesbot/cmd/main .

######## Start a new stage from scratch #######
FROM alpine:latest


RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates

WORKDIR /root/

# Copy the Pre-built binary file from the previous stage
COPY --from=builder /memesbot/cmd/main .

RUN chmod +x ./main

# Command to run the executable
CMD ["./main"]
```

And docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "7777:7777"
    environment:
      TELEGRAM_TOKEN: xxxx
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: What is the architecture of the system you're trying to run the docker image on?

Comment: I have macbook with macOS catalina

Comment: It doesn't work, I changed ```FROM golang:1.13 as builder``` to ```FROM golang:1.13-alpine as builder``` and have the same error ```app_1  | standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"```

Comment: This is not a problem with Docker, but with the golang code. Beside using /root/ as working directory (which I wouldn't advice) the rest is correct. I used your Dockerfile and a basic go application and everything works fine. Try to start the container without CMD and then connect to it and run your program inside the container - this might give you more information.